# Why Steps with parenthesis doesn't match in Groovy/Java Code when using Katalon/Cucumber?

Tags: regex, testing, groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

## Setting up:

The feature file does not allow to modify and it shows below.

```
Feature: create news
  Scenario: company check the news
    Given Java has a news with number (100)
```

## Step definition in Katalon / Groovy Code / Cucumber :

```
@Given("(.*) has a news with number ((\\d+))")
def check_user__with_news_number(String name, String num){

}
```

I had tried to use (something) or \(something), but the katalon does not recognize it.

> Katalon Studio
>   Version: 6.0.4
>   Build: 1
>
> Groovy Compiler version 2.4.7
>
> Java 8

Also: I had checked those issues already but the problem still is there

***error: Step Java has a news with number (100) does not have a matching glue code***

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/107

https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#escaping

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/103

Comment: Try escaping the parenthesis to match them literally `(.*) has a news with number \\((\\d+)\\)`

Comment: Escaping the inner parenthesis should do the trick - `"^(.*) has a news with number (\\(\\d+\\))$"`

Comment: Sorry @Thefourthbird The \\((\\d+)\\) does not work; The dollars sign gives me this in Katalon - "Groovy: illegal string body character after dollar sign"

Comment: Try with single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: @tim_yates The single slash gives errors - unexpected char

Comment: Single quotes, `'` not slash

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Unfortunately, the single quotes still give me errors on does not match gluu code in Katalon Studio. @tim_yates